# Windows authentication auto login in .net core API

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to do auto login to .net core API using windows authentication.

I have enabled windows authentication and rest all authentication is kept disabled. now I am trying to run the API. its prompt popup for enter the credentials for login.

I do not want any popup which asks users to enter login details. its should auto authenticate using the current login user. however, if I enter login details in that popup, still it's not getting authenticate, it keep asking me to enter the credentials.

Tried approach:

- In IIS, application pool's identity set custom account, (current login account which is administrator)
- Enable Anonymous authentication along with windows authentication. (when I do this then API does not give popup for login but its give null object for User.Identity.Name)

Reference:
I have implemented windows authentication by referring to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Note: When I run API from visual studio (IIS Express) its works fine, but when I host API to local IIS, then I am facing a challenge as I described above

Comment: either IIS and browser need to be enabled for Windows auth. In some browsers there is also a zone concept that may prevent sending windows auth to the server depending on the URL

Comment: Which browser(s) have you tested in?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander i have made configuration in IIS for enable windows authentication

Comment: @ADyson I am testing in chrome, I have also checked in IE, it now works same for me

Comment: Chrome does not automatically get the Kerberos/Windows credentials without a user prompt, unless it's configured in Group Policy. But IE or Edge should be able to - assuming the machine you're connecting from is part of the same Active Directory domain, and is connected to the domain at the time, and the site is in the right security zone. Also if you're accessing an intranet site, you may need to specify the FQDN in the address bar to avoid the prompt (in Chrome anyway).

Comment: pls check with fiddler or F12 tools how IIS talks with browser, this will narrow down

Comment: @ADyson, yes I am login using active directory user to my machine and my machine is in the domain, and I am accessing in the intranet, without http (not https).
If i do login in that popup still it not allow me. and about FQDN i don't know. could you please explain more for it

Comment: @FalcoAlexander , in F12 tools, it shows me Status Code: 401 Unauthorized

Comment: FQDN means [Fully Qualified Domain Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) (did you google it??). In other words instead of putting `http://intranet/appname/` into the browser you would put `http://intranet.yourdomain.com/appname`

Comment: Anyway if you're getting 401 even after you've entered the credentials, then maybe simply your account doesn't have permission to the particular IIS application. Have you set any specific authorisation rules either in IIS config or in the .NET config, or .NET code? Either that or you entered the wrong credentials!

Comment: there should be a 2+ step negotiate from browser and IIS, please check the headers. it may also be tricky with proxys or loadbalancers.

Comment: Thank you so much ADyson and Falco Alexander, I have solved my problem

Comment: solution : I have to whitelist a domain specified in the hosts file in order for windows authentication to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to whitelist a domain specified in the hosts file in order for windows authentication to work:

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
2. In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters`
3. Right-click Parameters, click New, and then click DWORD (32-bit) Value.
4. Type `DisableStrictNameChecking` and press ENTER.
5. Double-click the `DisableStrictNameChecking` registry value and type 1 in the Value data box, click OK
6. In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0`
7. Right-click MSV1_0, point to New, and then click Multi-String Value.
8. Type `BackConnectionHostNames`, and then press ENTER.
9. Right-click `BackConnectionHostNames`, and then click Modify.
10. In the Value data box, type the host name or the host names for the sites that are on the local computer, and then click OK.
11. Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the IISAdmin service.